# Store Specific Product Pricing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore

Need to setup branch specific pricing.600 Branches available each branch has same products but different pricing. Need to use zipcode to differentiate users and navigate them to corresponding branches/products. How can we do this in Magento 2 ? How much customisation needed ? is it possible to create 600 store views based on branches and set different price same product in different store views ? is it efficient ?

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is no any coding limitation for number of stores. But I have observed this with one of our client that as the number of stores increases it impacts performance due to re-indexing of products. Our Client had around 1 lakh products and around 10 stores. This was having us lot of issues. So finally we made a decision to switch back to single store and implement customisation to manage virtual stores.(We used Magento 1.9.x)

As you are talking around 600 Store, I would recommend you to have code customisation. But it all depends on your requirements, maintaining only prices differently per store is easily as compared to maintaining all the product attributes different each store level in you customisation.

Hope this gives you an idea.